# Howto find the size of a remote http/https directory (non recursively) using a given regexp from the command line

Tags: awk, sed, perl, http, html

I'm trying to find the size of a remote http/https directory (non recursively) using a given regexp (`\.mp4`) from the command line, is there a tool to do so or do I need to parse the `index.html` ?

EDIT0 : Here is the output I want to parse :

```
$ URL=https://cdn.sermons.love/mp4/Joseph%20Prince/
$ curl -s $URL | html2text -width $COLUMNS
****** Index of /mp4/Joseph Prince ******
[Icon ] Name                                                                           Last_modified      Size
Description
=======================================================================================================================
[[PARENTDIR]] Parent_Directory                                                                                    -
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Activate_the_Grace_Covenant_Through_Tongues.mp4                2019-04-16 22:32  428M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Align_Yourself_With_His_Purpose_and_Prosper.mp4                2019-04-16 22:36  452M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Amazing_Things_Happen_When_You_Flow_with_The_Spirit.mp4        2019-04-16 21:48  391M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Are_You_Frustrating_The_Favor_of_God.mp4                       2019-04-16 21:27  524M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_As_Jesus_Is,_So_Are_You.mp4                                    2019-04-16 22:28  894M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Blessings_Flow_Through_Grace.mp4                               2019-04-30 16:00  761M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Break_Every_Bad_Habit_With_Christ.mp4                          2019-04-16 22:48  462M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Break_Free_from_Addiction_and_Shame.mp4                        2019-04-16 22:12  388M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Come_As_You_Are_and_Receive_Your_Miracle.mp4                   2019-04-16 22:16  444M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Discerning_the_Lord's_Body_for_Greater_Health.mp4              2019-04-16 22:38  705M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Discover_God's_Way_to_Bless_You.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:28  524M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Don't_Fight_-_Feed!.mp4                                        2019-04-16 22:18  453M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Draw_The_Blood_Line_Of_Protection.mp4                          2019-04-25 13:21  804M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Easter_from_New_Creation_Church.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:23  843M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Enjoy_Jesus'_Supply_And_Delight_His_Heart.mp4                  2019-04-16 21:38  609M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Experience_God's_Restoration_For_Every_Regret.mp4              2019-04-16 22:37  421M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Experience_The_Grace_Revolution.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:41  189M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Find_Freedom_from_Every_Bondage_and_Addiction.mp4              2019-04-16 22:13  523M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Find_True_Fulfillment_In_Life.mp4                              2019-04-16 22:20  209M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Five_Words_To_Live_By__The_Battle_Is_The_Lord's.mp4            2019-04-16 21:57  226M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Fresh_Grace_For_Every_Trial.mp4                                2019-04-16 22:14  609M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Give_Jesus_Your_Cares_And_Live_Stress-Free.mp4                 2019-04-16 21:00  428M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_God_Is_A_Gracious_Rewarder.mp4                                 2019-04-16 22:42  224M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_God's_Blueprint_For_Leadership.mp4                             2019-04-16 21:30  776M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_God's_Perfect_Timing_In_The_Christmas_Story.mp4                2019-04-16 21:29  441M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_God's_Plan_To_Bless_You.mp4                                    2019-04-16 21:56  200M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Godly_Discipline_And_Correction_Brings_Promotion.mp4           2019-04-16 21:56  776M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Got_A_Weakness__God_Can_Use_You!.mp4                           2019-04-16 21:25  524M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Grace_Leadership_In_Action__How_To_Represent_God's_Heart.mp4   2019-04-16 22:30  732M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_He_Is_Risen.mp4                                                2019-04-16 21:47  442M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Healing_Flows_When_Grace_Is_Exalted.mp4                        2019-04-16 21:51  225M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Hear_Jesus_Only_And_Be_Uplifted.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:25  436M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Hear_the_Preached_Word_and_See_Breakthroughs.mp4               2019-04-16 21:31  459M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Hesed_Wisdom_to_Live_Skillfully.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:32  389M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_His_Healing_Is_For_The_Undeserving.mp4                         2019-04-16 22:20  217M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_His_Promises_Are_Yours_To_Own.mp4                              2019-04-16 22:23  524M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_His_Radiance_Upon_You_Brings_Favor.mp4                         2019-04-16 22:00  689M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_His_Resurrection,_Proof_Of_Your_Righteousness.mp4              2019-04-19 11:03  809M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_How_To_Be_Blessed_God's_Way.mp4                                2019-04-16 21:08  776M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_How_To_Live_Free_From_The_Curse.mp4                            2019-04-16 22:20  614M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_How_To_Make_Spirit-Led_Decisions.mp4                           2019-04-16 21:14  871M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_How_To_Pray_When_You_Have_No_Prayer.mp4                        2019-04-16 22:31  372M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_How_You_See_Jesus_Is_How_You_Will_Receive.mp4                  2019-04-16 21:50  657M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Immanuel__What_It_Means_To_Have_The_Lord_With_You.mp4          2019-04-16 21:30  210M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Inherit_God's_Promises_By_Faith,_Not_by_Works.mp4              2019-04-16 21:49  521M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Jesus_Draws_Near_When_You_Are_Discouraged_(Live_In_Israel).mp4 2019-04-16 21:18  561M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Jesus_Our_Jubilee.mp4                                          2019-04-16 21:53  694M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Jesus__Your_Reason_For_A_Fear-Free_Life.mp4                    2019-04-16 21:05  210M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Keys_To_Healing_In_The_Hebrew_Language.mp4                     2019-04-16 21:00  250M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Last_To_First_When_You_Trust_His_Goodness.mp4                  2019-04-16 22:50  781M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Learn_to_See_What_God_Sees.mp4                                 2019-04-16 21:46  419M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Let_Go_And_Let_His_Supply_Flow.mp4                             2019-04-16 22:33  461M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Let_Go_and_Flow_in_the_Vine_Life.mp4                           2019-04-16 22:26  458M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Live_Bold_Without_Guilt_and_Fear.mp4                           2019-04-16 22:04  427M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Live_Confident.mp4                                             2019-04-16 21:03  426M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Live_Life_Loved_By_The_Shepherd.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:39  428M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Live_Long,_Live_Strong.mp4                                     2019-04-16 22:35  621M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Live_Strong_In_The_Father's_Love.mp4                           2019-04-16 21:11  465M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Live_Undefeated_In_Christ.mp4                                  2019-04-16 21:57  438M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Make_Grace_Your_Way_of_Life.mp4                                2019-04-16 22:15  520M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Move_From_Predicament_To_Promotion.mp4                         2019-04-16 22:46  813M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_No_Condemnation_Leads_to_Divine_Health.mp4                     2019-04-16 21:59  685M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Not_Ashamed_Of_The_Gospel.mp4                                  2019-04-16 22:22  235M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Practical_Leadership_Keys_To_Living_Holy.mp4                   2019-04-16 21:36  829M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Receive_God's_Supply_for_All_of_Life's_Demands.mp4             2019-04-16 22:44  525M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Redemption_Truths_That_Bless_Your_Relationships.mp4            2019-04-16 21:09  217M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Rest_And_Receive_At_Jesus'_Feet.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:54  449M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Rest_In_Jesus'_Faith_For_Miracles.mp4                          2019-04-16 21:04  519M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Rest_Till_Your_Enemies_Become_Your_Footstool.mp4               2019-04-16 20:59  472M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Rest!_God_Is_Working_Behind_The_Scenes.mp4                     2019-04-16 22:43  523M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Say_Amen_To_God's_Promises.mp4                                 2019-04-16 21:45  521M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Set_Apart_To_Be_Kings_And_Priests.mp4                          2019-04-16 21:34  802M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Set_Free_to_Reign_in_Life.mp4                                  2019-04-16 22:06  528M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Speak_Out_and_Find_Strength.mp4                                2019-04-16 22:11  1.1G
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Speak_Out_by_Faith_and_Win.mp4                                 2019-04-16 21:20  412M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Stay_on_Grace_Ground_and_Experience_True_Life.mp4              2019-04-16 21:41  1.0G
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Stronger_Through_Every_Trial_And_Battle.mp4                    2019-04-16 22:47  789M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_Four_Gospels_Unlocked_for_Your_Blessings.mp4               2019-04-16 22:17  922M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_Friend_You_Can_Always_Depend_On.mp4                        2019-04-16 22:40  1.1G
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_God_Who_Goes_Before.mp4                                    2019-04-16 22:41  442M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_Health-Giving_Power_Of_A_Relaxed_Heart.mp4                 2019-04-16 21:10  613M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_Heart_of_the_Father_Revealed.mp4                           2019-04-16 21:44  468M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_Lord_Our_Righteousness.mp4                                 2019-04-16 21:02  423M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_Secret_of_Hearing_That_Brings_Untold_Blessings.mp4         2019-04-16 22:25  687M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_The_Spirit's_Rivers_Of_Provision_And_Healing.mp4               2019-04-16 21:52  404M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Turn_Your_Frustrations_Into_Breakthroughs.mp4                  2019-04-16 21:12  461M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Unlocking_Redemption's_Blessings_In_Your_Life.mp4              2019-04-16 21:43  686M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Victory_in_Your_Day_of_Trouble.mp4                             2019-04-16 22:05  456M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Walk_In_Constant_Victory_Over_Fear.mp4                         2019-04-16 22:09  1.1G
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_What_Is_Earnest_Prayer_To_God.mp4                              2019-04-16 22:31  215M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_What_Makes_No_Weapon_Prosper_Against_You.mp4                   2019-04-30 15:31  253M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Where_Is_God_In_The_Midst_Of_Your_Trouble.mp4                  2019-04-16 21:17  833M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Win_Over_Discouragement,_Depression_and_Burnout.mp4            2019-04-16 22:24  396M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Win_Over_Fear_and_Pride.mp4                                    2019-04-16 21:19  459M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Win_Over_Guilt_and_Condemnation.mp4                            2019-04-16 21:15  223M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Wisdom_For_Holy_Living.mp4                                     2019-04-16 21:07  791M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_You_Are_Forgiven.mp4                                           2019-04-16 22:04  440M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_You_Can_Live_Healed.mp4                                        2019-04-16 22:33  217M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Your_Blessed_Hope_In_Dark_Times.mp4                            2019-04-16 22:21  464M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Your_Only_Battle_is_Fight_to_Remain_at_Rest.mp4                2019-04-16 21:01  616M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Your_Past_Does_Not_Determine_Your_Future.mp4                   2019-04-16 21:22  685M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Your_Reason_For_A_Fear_Free_Life.mp4                           2019-04-16 21:13  468M
[[   ]] Joseph_Prince_-_Your_Security_in_Time_of_Shaking.mp4                           2019-04-16 22:03  681M
=======================================================================================================================
```

EDIT1 : I tried this bit it does not work because the file sizes in Gigs are not added :

```
$ curl -s $URL | html2text -width $COLUMNS | sed "s/M$//;s/G$/*1024/" | awk '/\.mp4/{size=$6;print"=> 6th field = "$6" size = "size >"/dev/stderr";total+=size}END{print "=> total = "total}'
=> 6th field = 428 size = 428
=> 6th field = 452 size = 452
=> 6th field = 391 size = 391
=> 6th field = 524 size = 524
=> 6th field = 894 size = 894
=> 6th field = 462 size = 462
=> 6th field = 388 size = 388
=> 6th field = 444 size = 444
=> 6th field = 705 size = 705
=> 6th field = 524 size = 524
=> 6th field = 453 size = 453
=> 6th field = 843 size = 843
=> 6th field = 609 size = 609
=> 6th field = 421 size = 421
=> 6th field = 189 size = 189
=> 6th field = 523 size = 523
=> 6th field = 209 size = 209
=> 6th field = 226 size = 226
=> 6th field = 609 size = 609
=> 6th field = 428 size = 428
=> 6th field = 224 size = 224
=> 6th field = 776 size = 776
=> 6th field = 441 size = 441
=> 6th field = 200 size = 200
=> 6th field = 776 size = 776
=> 6th field = 524 size = 524
=> 6th field = 732 size = 732
=> 6th field = 442 size = 442
=> 6th field = 225 size = 225
=> 6th field = 436 size = 436
=> 6th field = 459 size = 459
=> 6th field = 389 size = 389
=> 6th field = 217 size = 217
=> 6th field = 524 size = 524
=> 6th field = 689 size = 689
=> 6th field = 809 size = 809
=> 6th field = 776 size = 776
=> 6th field = 614 size = 614
=> 6th field = 871 size = 871
=> 6th field = 372 size = 372
=> 6th field = 657 size = 657
=> 6th field = 210 size = 210
=> 6th field = 521 size = 521
=> 6th field = 561 size = 561
=> 6th field = 694 size = 694
=> 6th field = 210 size = 210
=> 6th field = 250 size = 250
=> 6th field = 781 size = 781
=> 6th field = 419 size = 419
=> 6th field = 461 size = 461
=> 6th field = 458 size = 458
=> 6th field = 427 size = 427
=> 6th field = 426 size = 426
=> 6th field = 428 size = 428
=> 6th field = 621 size = 621
=> 6th field = 465 size = 465
=> 6th field = 438 size = 438
=> 6th field = 520 size = 520
=> 6th field = 813 size = 813
=> 6th field = 685 size = 685
=> 6th field = 235 size = 235
=> 6th field = 829 size = 829
=> 6th field = 525 size = 525
=> 6th field = 217 size = 217
=> 6th field = 449 size = 449
=> 6th field = 519 size = 519
=> 6th field = 472 size = 472
=> 6th field = 523 size = 523
=> 6th field = 521 size = 521
=> 6th field = 802 size = 802
=> 6th field = 528 size = 528
=> 6th field = 1.1*1024 size = 1.1*1024
=> 6th field = 412 size = 412
=> 6th field = 1.0*1024 size = 1.0*1024
=> 6th field = 789 size = 789
=> 6th field = 922 size = 922
=> 6th field = 1.1*1024 size = 1.1*1024
=> 6th field = 442 size = 442
=> 6th field = 613 size = 613
=> 6th field = 468 size = 468
=> 6th field = 423 size = 423
=> 6th field = 687 size = 687
=> 6th field = 404 size = 404
=> 6th field = 461 size = 461
=> 6th field = 686 size = 686
=> 6th field = 456 size = 456
=> 6th field = 1.1*1024 size = 1.1*1024
=> 6th field = 215 size = 215
=> 6th field = 450 size = 450
=> 6th field = 833 size = 833
=> 6th field = 396 size = 396
=> 6th field = 459 size = 459
=> 6th field = 223 size = 223
=> 6th field = 791 size = 791
=> 6th field = 440 size = 440
=> 6th field = 217 size = 217
=> 6th field = 464 size = 464
=> 6th field = 616 size = 616
=> 6th field = 685 size = 685
=> 6th field = 468 size = 468
=> 6th field = 681 size = 681
=> total = 49588.3
```

EDIT2 : I finally did that in Perl :

```
$ curl -s $URL | html2text -width $COLUMNS | perl -n -ale 'if(/mp4 /){$F[-1] =~ s/M$//;$F[-1] =~ s/G$/*1024/;$total+=eval $F[-1]}END{print "=> total = ",$total}'
=> total = 53987.2
```

EDIT3 : I also tried a combination of `pup` and `jq` but it seems date and size not in array, therefore it is not easy to parse :

```json
$ curl -s $URL | pup 'json{}' | jq '.[]  | .children[0].children[1].children[1].text' 
"- 2019-04-16 22:32  428M 2019-04-16 22:36  452M 2019-04-16 21:48  391M 2019-04-16 21:27  524M 2019-04-16 22:28  894M 2019-04-30 16:00  761M 2019-04-16 22:48  462M 2019-04-16 22:12  388M 2019-04-16 22:16  444M 2019-04-16 22:38  705M 2019-04-16 21:28  524M 2019-04-16 22:18  453M 2019-04-25 13:21  804M 2019-04-16 21:23  843M 2019-04-16 21:38  609M 2019-04-16 22:37  421M 2019-04-16 21:41  189M 2019-04-16 22:13  523M 2019-04-16 22:20  209M 2019-04-16 21:57  226M 2019-04-16 22:14  609M 2019-04-16 21:00  428M 2019-04-16 22:42  224M 2019-04-16 21:30  776M 2019-04-16 21:29  441M 2019-04-16 21:56  200M 2019-04-16 21:56  776M 2019-04-16 21:25  524M 2019-04-16 22:30  732M 2019-04-16 21:47  442M 2019-04-16 21:51  225M 2019-04-16 21:25  436M 2019-04-16 21:31  459M 2019-04-16 21:32  389M 2019-04-16 22:20  217M 2019-04-16 22:23  524M 2019-04-16 22:00  689M 2019-04-19 11:03  809M 2019-04-16 21:08  776M 2019-04-16 22:20  614M 2019-04-16 21:14  871M 2019-04-16 22:31  372M 2019-04-16 21:50  657M 2019-04-16 21:30  210M 2019-04-16 21:49  521M 2019-04-16 21:18  561M 2019-04-16 21:53  694M 2019-04-16 21:05  210M 2019-04-16 21:00  250M 2019-04-16 22:50  781M 2019-04-16 21:46  419M 2019-04-16 22:33  461M 2019-04-16 22:26  458M 2019-04-16 22:04  427M 2019-04-16 21:03  426M 2019-04-16 21:39  428M 2019-04-16 22:35  621M 2019-04-16 21:11  465M 2019-04-16 21:57  438M 2019-04-16 22:15  520M 2019-04-16 22:46  813M 2019-04-16 21:59  685M 2019-04-16 22:22  235M 2019-04-16 21:36  829M 2019-04-16 22:44  525M 2019-04-16 21:09  217M 2019-04-16 21:54  449M 2019-04-16 21:04  519M 2019-04-16 20:59  472M 2019-04-16 22:43  523M 2019-04-16 21:45  521M 2019-04-16 21:34  802M 2019-04-16 22:06  528M 2019-04-16 22:11  1.1G 2019-04-16 21:20  412M 2019-04-16 21:41  1.0G 2019-04-16 22:47  789M 2019-04-16 22:17  922M 2019-04-16 22:40  1.1G 2019-04-16 22:41  442M 2019-04-16 21:10  613M 2019-04-16 21:44  468M 2019-04-16 21:02  423M 2019-04-16 22:25  687M 2019-04-16 21:52  404M 2019-04-16 21:12  461M 2019-04-16 21:43  686M 2019-04-16 22:05  456M 2019-04-16 22:09  1.1G 2019-04-16 22:31  215M 2019-04-30 15:31  253M 2019-04-16 21:17  833M 2019-04-16 22:24  396M 2019-04-16 21:19  459M 2019-04-16 21:15  223M 2019-04-16 21:07  791M 2019-04-16 22:04  440M 2019-04-16 22:33  217M 2019-04-16 22:21  464M 2019-04-16 21:01  616M 2019-04-16 21:22  685M 2019-04-16 21:13  468M 2019-04-16 22:03  681M"
```

Isn't there an easier or "cleaner" way ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do with actual code examples? What is the "given regexp" that you mention and why is it the only way to find the storage size consumed by the contents of the directory? This sounds like an arbitrary exercise (like a homework problem). While there is nothing necessarily wrong with asking UNIX & Linux questions here for homework, it is easier to help work through the situation if we understand why constraints exist.

Comment: Are you trying to find the usage of a remote web server's files, or are you local to the web server?

Comment: @0xSheepdog I've just added an EDIT1 paragraph

Comment: can u share the output of `curl -s $URL| html2text -width $COLUMNS`

Comment: @msp9011 Sure, take a look at my EDIT0.

Comment: I also added an EDIT3 paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numfmt --from=...` to convert the file sizes to bytes, then you can easily sum them up:

```bsh
curl -s $URL | html2text -width $COLUMNS \
| awk '$3~/\.mp4/{print $6}' \
| LC_ALL=C numfmt --from=iec \
| paste -sd+ | bc

58044134197
```

- Add `| numfmt --to=iec` to get human readable sizes again, plus if you like `--format '%.1f'` to get decimal places.
- Use `--from=si` for 1000-based file sizes.
- Depending on your locals setting, you can omit `LC_ALL=C`, but I get an error with `1.1G`.

Comment: Can you please update your command so I can I have the total in GiB ?

Comment: I have this, see first bullet point ;-)

Comment: Thanks to you I rewrote my `totalSize` function to something much simpler. I can use it this way : `curl -s $URL | html2text -width $COLUMNS | grep '\.mp4' | totalSize 6` and the code of this function is now : `local column=$1;awk "{print \$$column}" | LC_ALL=C numfmt --from=iec | paste -sd+ | \bc -l | numfmt --to=iec` Thans a lot ! Jesus bless you !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
cat file | awk '{($NF ~ /G/)?$NF=$NF*1024:$NF=$NF*1} {sum += $NF} END {print sum}'
```

- multiply the last field with 1024 if it has `G`
- else multiply by 1 ( just to remove M, should be careful if u have K or something else)
- Finally, the sum of all values in the last field.

maybe u can replace the NF with 6 as ur mentioning it as a 6th field instead of last

Comment: You should note, that this will not work for small (`K`) and huge (`T`) files. or implement it ;-)

Comment: yes, I have mentioned it...